# Flutter: How to remove all previous routes when auth steam change state?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I would like to remove all previous routes and return to #WelcomeScreen
in case API response 401

**Code**

```
return GetMaterialApp(
        scrollBehavior: Behavior(),
        defaultTransition: Transition.leftToRight,
        translations: LanguageService(),
        locale: Get.locale,
        fallbackLocale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Obx(
          () {
            if (controller.state is Authenticated) {
              return const MainScreen();
            } else if (controller.state is UnAuthenticated) {
              return WelcomeScreen();
            } else if (controller.state is AuthSignIn) {
              return SignInScreen();
            } else if (controller.state is AuthSignUp) {
              return SignUpScreen();
            } else {
              return const SplashScreen();
            }
          },
        ),
        theme: AppTheme.light,
        darkTheme: AppTheme.dark,
        getPages: AppPages.list);
```

**Controller**

```
AuthController auth = Get.find();
Future<void> fetchUsers() async{
    var response = await userService.findAll();
    //......
    if(response.code==401){
       auth.authStateStream.value = UnAuthenticated();
       Get.back();
       Get.back();

    }

}
```

Currently, on state change to UnAuthenticated, it returns to WelcomeScreen
but it does not remove some previous pages. I need to use Get.back one or more depending on the pages I have pushed.

Is there any better solution for this, please give me a suggestion or advice.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
Get.offAll(()=>WelcomeScreen());
```